# How do I select a text within an element within another element

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

How do I get the text "Tuesday" from tbody and print it using python and selenium?

```
<tbody class="tr-border-bottom">
                                                <tr>
                                                        <th class="pb-15 text-left fixed-side">
                                                        <a href="javascript:changeDate('25 May 2021');">25 May 2021</a><br />
                                                        **Tuesday**
                                                        </th>
    
                                                                            <td class="pb-15 text-center"><span class="c-gray">n/a</span></td>
                                                                            <td class="pb-15 text-center"><span class="c-gray">n/a</span></td>
                                                                            <td class="pb-15 text-center"><span class="c-gray">n/a</span></td>
                                                                            <td class="pb-15 text-center"><span class="c-gray">n/a</span></td>
                                                                    <td class="pb-15 text-center">
                                                                        <a href="#" id="1279867_5_25/5/2021 12:00:00 AM_0" class="slotBooking">
                                                                            6:10 PM ✔
                                                                        </a>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                            <td class="pb-15 text-center"><span class="c-gray">n/a</span></td>
                                                </tr>
```

This is my trial using xpath , I am new to this and I cannot get this right , syntax error.

```
Booking = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(//tbody/tr/th/text())
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question with code trial?

Comment: I added my trial

Answer (score 0):

It should be easy.
Try:

```
from selenium import webdriver
 
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("your site address")
your_text = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".text-left.fixed-side").text
```

After you get the text, you can split it.